# How to create histogram using bash with the custom log structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need some help in getting the bash `histogram` of the log information generated from the server.
The log structure is like this

```
HH:MM:SS <column 1>,<column 2>,<topic name>,<Start_Time>,<End_Time>
```

I want to extract the `HH:MM:SS` and `<topic name>` and the `difference in time` and show

```
16:12:33 topic_1 02 hrs 30 mins 00 sec ----------------------------->
16:12:34 topic_2 01 hrs 00 mins 00 sec ------------->
16:12:35 topic_3 00 hrs 02 mins 00 sec ->
16:12:36 topic_4 00 hrs 30 mins 00 sec ------>
16:12:37 topic_5 00 hrs 15 mins 00 sec --->
16:12:38 topic_6 00 hrs 20 mins 00 sec ---->
16:12:39 topic_7 00 hrs 25 mins 00 sec ----->
16:12:40 topic_8 00 hrs 02 mins 00 sec ->
...
...
...
```

I tried searching and could not come up with any proper way to cut and get this done efficiently.

This is where I reached

```
grep <search_term> log_file | cut -f2,16 -d' ' | awk -F, '{print $5-$4 "," $0}' | awk -F, '{print $1  " " $4}'
```

Can any one help?

Comment: Post ~5 lines of sample input. You can do this all in a *single* call to `awk`. The challenge will be to scale the histogram output so it is useful when viewed where you are viewing it. You can simply loop and `print "-"` based on the difference and add a `print ">"` after the loop exits.

Comment: How can we tell the `difference in time` if we don't know the date(s) involved? DST transitions, leap days and leap seconds play a part in these kinds of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring DST, leap seconds, leap days, etc.:

```
$ cat file
01:02:03 <column 1>,<column 2>,topic_1,01:02:03,01:12:10
01:02:03 <column 1>,<column 2>,topic_2,01:02:03,01:18:20
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    split($(NF-1),b,/:/)
    split($NF,e,/:/)
    begSecs = 60*60*b[1] + 60*b[2] + b[3]
    endSecs = 60*60*e[1] + 60*e[2] + e[3]

    durSecs = endSecs - begSecs
    durMins = int(durSecs/60)
    durHrs  = int(durMins/60)

    if      ( t == "h" ) { dur = durHrs  }
    else if ( t == "m" ) { dur = durMins }
    else                 { dur = durSecs }

    dashes = sprintf("%*s",dur,"") ">"
    gsub(/ /,"-",dashes)

    sub(/ .*/,"",$1)
    print $1, $3, durHrs, "hrs", durMins-60*durHrs, "mins", durSecs-60*durMins, "secs\t" dashes
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
01:02:03 topic_1 0 hrs 10 mins 7 secs  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
01:02:03 topic_2 0 hrs 16 mins 17 secs ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

.

```
$ awk -v t='m' -f tst.awk file
01:02:03 topic_1 0 hrs 10 mins 7 secs  ---------->
01:02:03 topic_2 0 hrs 16 mins 17 secs ---------------->
```

You didn't say if each `-` should represent a second, a minute, an hour, or something else so I showed how to modify that by setting `t`.